# Execution failed for task ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'

Tags: android

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mycompany.newlogin"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            multiDexEnabled true
        }
    }
    productFlavors {

    }
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}



dependencies {
    //compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.1'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5'
    compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
}
```

Comment: The error is                                                                                                  Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'.
> java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/apache/http/HttpMessage.class,                          how can i resolve this please

Answer (score 0):

Try by removing this line `useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'`
 from your gradle file, and build again.